# Column value return null

Tags: laravel, api, react-native

I have a problem with my code, my value in form has always return null.

Here's my code:

```
update = async() => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    try{
        await fetch('http://0872b1689xxx.ngrok.io/api/xxx/update/' + this.state.id, {
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept'       : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem('api_token'),
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "nip"     : this.state.nip,
                "name"    : this.state.name,
                "email"   : this.state.email,
                "password": this.state.password
            })
        }).then(res => res.text())
        .then(resData => {
            alert(resData);

        });
    }catch(e){
        alert("");
    }
}
```

When I alert(this.state.nip) it works its not null but when I send in my api its say nip null but only my password has value

[image]

Here's my API code:

```
public function validator($request)
{
    $rules = [
        'nip'           => ['required', 'string'],
        'name'          => ['required', 'string'],
        'email'         => ['required', 'string'],
        'password'      => ['required'],
    ];

    return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}

public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request);
  
        $data = [
            'nip'       => $request->nip,
            'name'      => $request->name,
            'role_id'   => Auth::user()->role_id,
            'email'     => $request->email,
            'password'  => Hash::make($request->password),
        ];
        $update = $user->update($data);

        return response()->json("b", 200); 
}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Is `nip` fillable in your user model?

Comment: yes.

    protected $fillable = [
        'nip', 'name', 'email', 'role_id', 'password',
    ];

Comment: what does `$validator->passes()` return?

Comment: try this code  return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules)->validate(); to correctly implement validation and please share screenshots of your network that shows the parameters with values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're doing nothing with the result of the validation.

To validate a request with no special handling you are usually using `$request->validate()` which fails with a `ValidationException`.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic):

> [...] if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper
>   error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the
>   case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be
>   generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // If this fails, it throws an ValidationException which gets handled by your exception handler.
    $request->validate([
        'nip'           => ['required', 'string'],
        'name'          => ['required', 'string'],
        'email'         => ['required', 'string'],
        'password'      => ['required'],
    ]);

    // The data here has been validated and will be suficcient for your query.
    $data = [
        'nip'       => $request->nip,
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'role_id'   => Auth::user()->role_id,
        'email'     => $request->email,
        'password'  => Hash::make($request->password),
    ];
    $update = $user->update($data);

    return response()->json("b", 200);
}
```

If you need to have the rules in another method to reuse them for example, you would need to use the result of your `validator` function and handle the error yourself.

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $validation = $this->validator($request);

    // Abort if the validator fails and send your custom error response.
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validation->errors()]);
    }

    // The data here has been validated and will be suficcient for your query.
    $data = [
        'nip'       => $request->nip,
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'role_id'   => Auth::user()->role_id,
        'email'     => $request->email,
        'password'  => Hash::make($request->password),
    ];

    $update = $user->update($data);

    return response()->json("b", 200);
}
```

Comment: its still same.its return null.have i a mistake in my code react native?

Comment: but when i get value in my react native like alert(this.state.nip) it give me a value what i input it but when i send in api laravel it throwing null

Comment: even i am not using validator it cannot update my database because it sends a null value

Comment: only my password has a value

Comment: The error message definitively comes from within your Laravel application. Unfortulately I cannot help you with the problem on the React side. Does it work if you manually send the request to that route, like with Postman? Does React throw any errors in the developer console? How does the JSON look before it gets send to the server, are all of your values included?

Comment: when i use postman its looks fine my api controller.and then when in the react side before its send to api, its give me a all value.but when i send it to api only password has value

Comment: How does the request look like in the developer console? Can you see the data? See: https://i.imgur.com/Ao6NQpL.png